# Determining the difference between two shapefiles

Tags: qgis, spatial-analysis

I have two shapefiles which contain data on the assessment of the quality of data collection in different areas.
data set 1 can be considered the most up to date and as such the template on which I wish to asses data set 2.

I am looking for way to compare the two data sets and highlight areas where the data quality does not match. The problem I have is that the second dataset does not have the same extent as the first and has a number of additional polygons so they are not alike. The template file for example might have a large area with quality 1 but in the second dataset there may be several smaller areas with data quality 2, 3, and 4 in the same area.

I have both QGIS and ArcGIS Pro at my disposal.

Comment: Try Union geoprocessing tool

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood your question, you only want to compare attribute values, not the actual geometries (shapes) of the two layers. If you have one common, unique attribute like a name (e.g. for administrative units) or a common unique id, you can use the join tab in the Vector properties dialog, see documentation: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=join#joins-properties.

In this way, you can add the data from layer 2 to the attribute table of layer 1 and than make your comparison, e.g. using field calculator. For a more focused answer, please re-formulate your question.